# One page website made with PagePiling.js very slow on chrome but fast on safari/Firefox

Tags: performance, google-chrome, loading, pagepiling.js

Can anybody lend me some advice on this?

This website:

www.mrchrismartin.co.uk

I have tried streamlining the loading time and asynchronous loading of scripts and nothing seems to affect the age long loading time on chrome compared to other browsers? I will be most grateful for any available advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I use covering background images, too. The performance got better after using `background: url(bg.jpg);` instead of `background-image: url(bg.jpg);` in the css.